# Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 installs but still says Update 1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, updates

We were running VS2012 Pro Update 1 and just installed Update 4 (VS2012.4.exe) yesterday. The installation appeared to be successful - no error messages, etc., and the control panel definitely shows that Update 4 (11.0.61030) was installed.

However, when we start VS it still says that we're running Update 1 (11.0.51106.01).

We re-ran vs2012.4.exe with the "Repair" option and re-booted the server, but nothing changes.

We're running on Windows Server 2008 R2, SP1 with .Net 4.5.50948.

Is there something else we have to do?

Comment: Where is that info? In the About dialog?

Comment: It is a cumulative update, but that doesn't get put to the test very often.  Pioneers have arrows in their back.  If you'd call Microsoft Support about this then they'll probably ask you to do the obvious thing and install Updates 2 and 3 first.  Or send them your log files, only way to diagnose this.

Comment: The current version ("Update 1") is shown in "About". The theoretically installed version ("Update 4") is shown in the Control panel.

Comment: I went looking to try and get just Update 2 and Update 3 but can't find them - anything about updates always seems to point to (only) the latest/greatest - Update 4. Anybody have any direct links to just Update 2 and Update 3?