# Determine Visual Studio Update Version in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Is it possible to determine in init.ps1, whether Update 2 (or later) of Visual Studio 2012 Premium is installed? I found `$dte.Version` and `$dte.Edition`, but more detailed information seems to be missing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dte.Version` should be the Information you need. The following post shows the version numbers for Update 1 (11.0.51106.01) and Update 4 (11.0.61030.00) (I can confirm this value)

[Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 installs but still says Update 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532258/visual-studio-2012-update-4-installs-but-still-says-update-1)

**Edit**:

OK, seems to be a bit harder: 
You can retrieve the path to devenv.exe with `$dte.FullName` and then retrieve the file-version.

My powershell knowledge is very limited, so here is the c# code:

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe")
```

The resulting FileVersionInfo has the property `ProductVersion` which contains the information you need.

Comment: Tried to verify using NuGet console, but I get `11.0` using `PM> $dte.Version`. Visual Studio is on Update 4. `$dte.Version.GetType()` returns `String` - so no luck here.

Comment: Thank you for your update. `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($dte.FullName)` gives me a very detailed output. However, the Update Version is missing. I will now try to figure out, which `ProductBuildPart` corresponds to Update 2.
More elegant solutions are highly appreciated...

Comment: For Reference, Update 2 has ProductBuildPart 60315.